# Not able to add or Remove Module in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Not Able to add or remove new module or module dependency library in android studio 3.1.3 in earlier version its working fine. It is showing Internal IDE error while am trying to add or remove new library. I have already done invalidate caches and restart the android studio but still not able to add or remove.

Comment: Which library are you trying to remove ? And What the exception you are facing, Please mention.

Comment: @Ankita-user3449434 I have some custom aar files module to import. its showing internal IDE error.